# Is it correct to say “Level stars counts”? (in a video game)

Tags: american-english

In a video game, we are using a sentence to tell the user that if he fails to reach end of the level, he will lose the stars he collected in that level.
which one is better? or is there something better?

> 1. Level stars counts only if you finish the level
> 2. Level stars are counted only if you finish the level.

And, is it OK to have two "level"s in the sentence, or we should replace or remove one of them? any ideas?

Comment: How about: "If the level is not completed, any level stars collected on that level are lost?"

Comment: "Level stars" is plural, so it would at least have to be "Level stars **count**", not *counts*.  Yes, it's OK to use *level* twice in the sentence.  There's no reason you can't use the same word twice in a sentence, and the first one here is actually serving as a *noun adjunct* to modify "stars": what kind of stars are they?  *Level* stars.

Comment: @mark-ripley We want the sentence to be positive (not to contain "lose", "not complete", "will not", etc)

Comment: @stangdon these are just stars, like coins, that the character collects by moving over them.

Comment: @roointan - Sure, then *level stars* sounds absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

> level stars

is not a jargon phrase for your game.

You could say

> Stars for this level are only *kept* if you finish the level.
>   Stars for this level are only *earned* if you finish the level.

Comment: I agree. "Level stars" might be confusing to some, whereas "stars for this level" is more descriptive. In fact, it might be even better to say "Stars *collected* during this level are only kept if you *complete* the level."